# Nvim Coc: How to change matching text color in suggestion box

Tags: neovim, coc.nvim

[This](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/blob/master/data/schema.json) is what the official repo of coc.nvim gives as documentation for Coc configuration.

An update changed the option names, and the defaults, I'm willing to revert it, but I'm out of ideas. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPUJi.png) is what my suggestions look like. I want to change the color of the blue parts to the same color as the rest since I have bad eye sight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it by `CocMenuSel`, add something like `hi CocMenuSel ctermbg=109 guibg=#13354A` to your vimrc.